# Why does my visualization not showing distributed geom_point?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using ggplot2 to work on my assignment. My dataset is gapminder, and I need to create a plot that looks like this:

[image: assignment image]

The question provided is:

> Try to replicate the graph. As said above, you should try some filtering (e.g. by doing something like data = subset(NAME DATA, continent %in% c("Asia", "Oceania")).
>
> Moreover, I manually picked the colors for the two continents. I’ve used “seagreen” and “slateblue4”, but have a look at http:// [www.stat.columbia.edu/~tzheng/files/Rcolor.pdf](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/%7Etzheng/files/Rcolor.pdf) and pick your own favorite colors.
>
> Additionally, I set a theme (theme_bw()), and removed the title of the legend with theme(legend.title=element_blank()). Include the code you used in your RMarkown file and provide a short description and interpretation of the resulting graph.

So far, I have succeeded in creating a plot that looks similar, but **my geom_point seems not quite the same.** This is the plot I got

[image]

Below is the code that I wrote:

```
library(gapminder)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
(out <- lm(formula = lifeExp ~ gdpPercap + pop + continent, data = gapminder))
(min_gdp = min(gapminder$gdpPercap))
(max_gdp = max(gapminder$gdpPercap))
(med_pop = median(gapminder$pop))
(pred_df = expand.grid(gdpPercap = (seq(from = min_gdp, to = max_gdp, length.out = 100)),
                       pop = med_pop, continent = c("Africa", "Americas", "Asia", "Europe", "Oceania")))
(pred_out = predict(object = out,
                    newdata = pred_df,
                    interval = "predict"))
pred_df$lifeExp <- predict(out, newdata = pred_df)
pred_df = cbind(pred_df, pred_out)
filtered_data <- subset(pred_df, continent %in% c("Africa", "Europe"))
line_colors <- c("seagreen", "slateblue4")
ggplot(data = filtered_data, aes(x = gdpPercap, y = lifeExp, color = continent)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lwr, ymax = upr, fill = continent), 
              alpha = 0.2, linetype = 0, color = NA) +
  geom_point(aes(color = continent), size = 3, alpha = 0.8) +
  geom_smooth() +
  scale_x_log10(labels = scales::dollar) +
  scale_color_manual(values = line_colors) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = line_colors) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(16, 17)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank())
```

What can I try next?

Comment: It looks like the assignment image plots actual values in the geom_points layer, while you are plotting predicted values from your regression. Try `geom_point(aes(color = continent), size = 3, alpha = 0.8, data = subset(gapminder, continent %in% c("Africa", "Europe"))) +`

Comment: Oh my goodness it works!! Thank you so much for your help. You saved me from the endless agony. Thank you!